# javascript check values are same or not within double quotes?

Tags: javascript

In javascript if any variable has multiple values seperated by comma within double quotes,then how to check that values are same or not

```
      var str= "0,1,-1";
```

How to check this variable.

Comment: you mean you want to check either these 3 values are same or not?? mean 0 and 1 and -1 are same or  not??

Comment: yes its may be like this also, var str="0,1,1,0,2"

Comment: yes just its all are same or not ie, true are false

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators?v=test

Comment: "0,1,-1" is the same as "0,1,-1" ... anything else, is different

Comment: You might [*split*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) on the comma, then use [*every*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to see if all values are the same as the first one.

Comment: perhaps you want to split the string on `','` and do something with the resulting array?

Comment: @Ammu, make it more clear. What should be the result for this input `1,1,1` and for `1,0,-2,1` ? Post valid and invalid examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author wants to compare these 3 values. You most separate this variable with `split`:

```
var str= "0,1,-1",
arr = str.split(',');
```

*all are same or not ie, true are false* compare this array with function `every`

```
     var str= "0,1,-1",
     arr = str.split(',');

    var res = arr.every(function (item) {
       return item == arr[0];
    })

    console.log(res);
```

Comment: No, you're right, OP does say check if *all are same or not* - hidden in a comment rather than the question itself :p

Answer (score 1):

Short solution using `String.prototype.split()` and [*Set*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) object:

```js
var hasSameValues = function (s) {
    return (new Set(s.split(','))).size === 1;
};

console.log(hasSameValues("0,1,-1"));
console.log(hasSameValues("1,1,1"));
console.log(hasSameValues("2,-2,2"));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can split and then check for every item in splitted array.

check the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stdeepak22/78jgswz8/)

code is below -

```
var val = "1, 01, 0001";
var result = function(val)
{
    var l = val.length;
    if(l == 0)
    {
      return false;
    }
    else
    {
      //because all the values in 'val' fields are number
      var f = Number.parseInt(val[0]) ;
      for(i=1; i< l; i++)
      {
         if(Number.parseInt(val[i]) != f)
         {
           return false;
         }         
      }
      return true;
    }
}(val.split(','))

alert(result);
```